# Clickable border cell in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've already created a clickable cell in a table with:

```
<td>
    <a href="link.hmlt" style = "display:block; width:100%;height:100%> &nbsp;</a>
</td>
```

But the table has visible borders, and when the mouse is exactly over one these borders, the link does not work.

How can I make the border also clickable? I've tried a JavaScript solution:

```
<td onclick="document.location='link.html'" > </td>
```

Here the borders are handled, but it's not satisfactory, because in this case the "special" click types are not correctly handled (e.g. "ctrl + click" doesn't open a new tab).

Can we make the borders clickable in HTML/CSS? Do we have to use JavaScript?

EDIT : here is a minimal sample of what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/pUunJ/1/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why your trying to click the "borders" of the cell, but being part of the cell, they should register the click event. Aside from that, there is no way to handle click events on the borders for they are not treated as being a separate object. Could you possible provide a JSFiddle? Plus, in you first code block `<a href="link.hmlt" style = "display:block; width:100%;height:100%> &nbsp;</a>`, you accidentally have the link going to `link.hmlt` and not `link.html`. Maybe this is just an error in your example and not in your actual project.

Comment: Border is part of the cell and is included in element width calculations, so you should be able to click on it: http://jsfiddle.net/tnetG/1/

Comment: @TylerH it's visibly not the same with cells in a tab : http://jsfiddle.net/pUunJ/1/

Comment: @Sebastien That's because, as the answer below has said, you've put your border around the cell rather than around the link. Of course the cell's border isn't going to be clickable; the cell isn't a link, it simply *contains* a link.

Answer (score 1):

first off, stay away from inline styling and inline javascript.

I believe you issue is you apply the border to the table cells, if you want the link to include the borders apply the border to link link instead of the table cell

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2MCEz/1/)

Comment: These borders are pretty small; maybe make them 5px (in the future) so it's easier to click them? :-)

Comment: Thanks, but now the border is double of the size for internal cells: http://jsfiddle.net/2MCEz/2/
Plus, it mess up the box size calculations (at leat under Chrome)...

Comment: that is due to the border not being included in the 100% width.

Comment: add box-sizing:border-box; to the table a {}